# creation of socket operation

Tags: c

when compiling a raw socket program i get the following error how to solve this

```
               socket: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Hint: try performing only operations that are permitted.

Comment: could you please give a bit more information? Operating System, code snippet around the error-reporting part, etc. Anything that helps us, to locate your problem and solve it.

Comment: Is it when compiling or when running?

Comment: It means skript kiddies are not permitted to run exploits they don't understand. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[Superuser privileges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) are usually required to create and manipulate raw sockets.

Comment: Only if the port if below to 1024

Comment: @blue112: Only superuser can create a raw socket because with a raw socket you can write your own TCP stack and circumvent the privileged port restriction if you were allowed to do it as a non superuser.

Comment: Oh, a raw socket, sorry for my comment then.